# Outputting a cell x number of times in an array format

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

Using Google Sheets:
Need to display a vertical list, where each occurrence in the A column of sheet1 is repeated based on the number in the B column of sheet1.

I've created a [dummy file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KAiu_U1HcaYoReiIUc_yRUZ6nt4GcGzqoyPd8ox027c/edit?usp=sharing) to show what I'm trying to do and shared it for viewing:

I can do a single item using:

```
=transpose(split(rept(Sheet1!A2&";",Sheet1!B2),";"))
```

But can't figure out how to keep going for the rest of the items in the list.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Thanks user0 for your help. Took awhile to translate it to my actual more complicated worksheet, but I got it sorted. Only problem I was having was it was pulling from Sheet1, but dropping the last 4 rows. If I added 4 dummy entries, it would work.

Comment: Hi MainelyTom and welcome to Web Apps SE. Glad you got an answer working. A note though; comments are for improving questions and answers, not for conversation (even what I'm typing now!). You can edit your future questions whenever you have more info to add, and [upvote or accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) helpful answers. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT(
 INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)), ",")&",", 
 INDIRECT("Sheet1!B2:B"&COUNTA(B1:B))))), ","))
```

[image: 0]